# About the usage of the term signal to noise ratio (SNR) in some posts on meta.

Tags: discussion

In many posts on meta I've seen a term called signal to noise ratio, which i know as a concept in statistical signal processing but I am not able to make out the intuition behind using this term in here and I'd like to be enlightned on this.

Answer (score 9):

The second paragraph of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) sums it up pretty well:

> Signal-to-noise ratio is sometimes used informally to refer to the ratio of useful information to false or irrelevant data in a conversation or exchange. For example, in online discussion forums and other online communities, off-topic posts and spam are regarded as "noise" that interferes with the "signal" of appropriate discussion.

Comment: In other words, it is a metaphor.

Comment: ...and in all honesty, I'd have figured somebody with signal processing expertise would easily figure out the metaphor... :D